# Partial Differentiation problem help

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, derivatives, partial-derivative

I was hoping someone could help me with the following problem. I've done some partial differentiation and some differential equations, but I'm surely missing something in regard to this following problem.

$$u = \frac{p-q}{q-r}$$

$p=x+y+z,\space q=x-y+z,\space r=x+y-z$.

I'm supposed to calculate $\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}$ at $(\sqrt{3},2,1)$.

I have no idea how to approach this sum, as clearly if I substitute p,q,r in the equation, all the $x$ terms cancel out. However, the final answer is supposed to be $-2$. Can anyone tell me how to approach this type of problems ?

Comment: There may be some typo.  For the given definitions the  answer is $0$.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy that is exactly what I thought, but evidently some websites like Chegg and others have some solutions, though they are blurred and all. I'm not sure if those are valid though. To me, it seems the answer is $0$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is most definitely zero.

[image]

FYI, the command `Derivative[k1,k2,...,kn][F]` computes the function
$$\frac{\partial^{k_1+\dots +k_n}F}{\partial x_1^{k_1}\dots\partial x_n^{k_n}}$$
Where $x_i$ denotes the $i$th argument of $F$. Then,

`Derivative[k1,k2,...,kn][F][x1,...,xn]`

Evaluates said function at the point $(x_1,\dots,x_n)$.